# Unable to read excel file using MultipartFormdataInput in Rest Call

Tags: javascript, java, jboss7.x, inputstream, multipartform-data

I am using MultipartFormDataInput to read excel file in REST call. My server code is mentioned below.

```
@POST
@Path("/UploadedFile")

@Consumes("multipart/form-data")

@Produces({ "text/html" })

    public /*JSONArray*/ String UploadedFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) throws Exception     
    {
        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file");
        System.out.println("in rest call file got" );

        InputPart inputPart = inputParts.get(0);
        InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        .....

    }
```

Now this always throw exception while reading inputStream? Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this or is there any other way I can do this as I am totally new in this area

exception is:

```
Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet and class type java.io.FileInputStream
```